# Is the diagnosis from a battery/starter/alternator tester meaningful?

Tags: electrical, battery, alternator, starter, testing

At many auto parts stores they will test - often for free - a vehicle's electrical system by attaching a device to the positive and negative terminals of the battery.  That's all they do.  Then you turn on your vehicle, and, like magic, they can tell you if your battery, starter, or alternator is faulty.  Not only that, they can provide very specific information regarding any faults.

Is the information produced by these systems meaningful?

What if more than one component is actually faulty?

Answer (score 2):

This test is rudimentary, but efficient.

- Testing the battery voltage with the car off tells you the current state of the battery (can it hold a charge)
- Testing the battery voltage with the car on tells you the state of the alternator (can it recharge the battery)
- Measuring the battery draw while you are starting the car tells you the current state of the starter (is it drawing the correct amount of current)

Any deviation from normal, and by how much, provides well-educated guesses.

Comment: A small nit, but on the third point you're measuring the voltage drop while cranking rather than the current drawn.

Comment: @dlu How would you rephrase *"is it drawing the correct amount of current"*?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I would measure current draw from the starter, but that may not be the specific test auto parts stores are doing. :)

Comment: Testing the battery by itself (which sounds like what's being done in the first step) also tells you if the battery is charged, and, with the tester I've seen used, charges it if it isn't. If it can't be charged, then it doesn't hold a charge and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Once you've determined that the battery is okay, starting the vehicle tells you that the starter works.

Comment: (If the vehicle won't start, it's a problem with the starter or the electrical connections. The alternator doesn't factor into the equation, at this point.)

Comment: Once the vehicle is running, the voltage across the battery is the voltage the alternator is putting out, which is higher than the voltage measured in the first step—so that it recharges the battery. If it's not higher than the voltage from step 1, the alternator isn't working, so the battery is being discharged but not recharged; the car won't start with a discharged battery.

Comment: But those are all tests you can perform with a load tester, a voltmeter, and a battery charger. What the store's actually doing, I'd be interested to find out.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard, I think what I'd say is, "The voltage drop while the starter motor is running gives you information about the condition of the starter (is it drawing too much current, and thus pulling the battery down more than is to be expected) and about the battery's ability to handle a starting load."

Comment: @MathieuK. That's right, you could do those tests with just a volt meter, the battery test (IIRC) just gives you the ability to apply a known load and I think the scale on many of them is coded to help you interpret the results. Modern ones may include a digital meter and a microcontroller that allows more sophisticated testing.

Comment: @dlu Thanks! What type of *more sophisticated testing*?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard, I'm making this up (i.e., I haven't actually seen devices that do this – in part because I haven't looked), but for example with a microcontroller you could detect and record very short duration events that you might miss (or because of meter ballistics, might not even be able to see at all). You could also have tables of voltage drops that would enable the device to give you better feedback on the state of components, you might also be able to use ripple from the alternator to measure engine speed and use that to better evaluate alternator output.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard, in other words, better educated guesses :-)